# Finding longest word in a sentence

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, strings

A problem from Coderbyte. Find the longest word in a sentence after removing the punctuations and if two or more words are of same length return the first word

Below is my solution:

```
def cleanWord(word):
  # To remove punctuations
  punctuations = ['!','.','\'','"',',','&']
  new_word = ''

  for c in word:
    if c in punctuations:
      continue
    else:
      new_word += c  

  return new_word    

def LongestWord(sen):

  words = sen.split(' ')

  word_lengths = {}
  # finding length of each word
  for word in words:
      clean_word = cleanWord(word)
      if len(clean_word) not in word_lengths.keys():
        word_lengths[len(clean_word)] = word

  longest_word_length = max(word_lengths.keys())
  longest_word = word_lengths[longest_word_length]
  #print(word_lengths)

  return longest_word
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def cleanWord(word):
  # To remove punctuations
```

The comment is  a better name `without_punctuation`. Also you should be following snake case as per PEP-8.

Much of your logic in the longest word function can be handled by `max` with a key function. The overall solution can be written like so.

```
def without_punctuation(text):                                                  
    translator = str.maketrans('','',string.punctuation)                        
    return text.translate(translator)                                           
                                                                                
def longest_word(sentence):                                                     
    words = without_punctuation(sentence).split()                               
    return max(words,key=len)
```

Comment: If the sentence is written like your code, i.e., without the standard space after commas (rather bad for someone pointing out PEP 8 :-), then you incorrectly combine words.